# Confusion around Access, ID, and Refresh JWT authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt

I've been developing my first REST API to serve as the back-end for a mobile application. I'm pulling info from different resources, and am a little confused when it comes to the token implementation (I'm using JWT).

The access token is used to ensure that the requester has access to the resource that is being called. My understanding is that I will then encode the user details in the ID Token, such that the relevant information can be returned. The refresh token is used as a security mechanism, to keep the user authenticated after the short-lived ID and access tokens expire.

The access token seems a little redundant, and maybe it is an interchangeable term for ID token? Can I just remove that part from my authentication scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the proposed scheme access and ID tokens are used interchangeably and do not provide any value over the other. All information provided in the access token can be stored in the ID token, or vice versa. The entire authentication scheme will then simply consist of an access token (containing both info on access permissions, and user info), and a refresh token (ensuring that users don't need to login again every t minutes).